# Maximum Product Subarray issue

Tags: java, algorithm

Here is the problem and code (I searched for solutions and most are similar, post one easy to read), my question is for below two lines,

```
 imax = max(A[i], imax * A[i]);
 imin = min(A[i], imin * A[i]);
```

why we need to consider A[i] individually and why not just write as,

```
 imax = max(imin * A[i], imax * A[i]);
 imin = min(imin * A[i], imax * A[i]);
```

Find the contiguous subarray within an array (containing at least one number) which has the largest product.

For example, given the array [2,3,-2,4],
the contiguous subarray [2,3] has the largest product = 6.

```
int maxProduct(int A[], int n) {
    // store the result that is the max we have found so far
    int r = A[0];

    // imax/imin stores the max/min product of
    // subarray that ends with the current number A[i]
    for (int i = 1, imax = r, imin = r; i < n; i++) {
        // multiplied by a negative makes big number smaller, small number bigger
        // so we redefine the extremums by swapping them
        if (A[i] < 0)
            swap(imax, imin);

        // max/min product for the current number is either the current number itself
        // or the max/min by the previous number times the current one
        imax = max(A[i], imax * A[i]);
        imin = min(A[i], imin * A[i]);

        // the newly computed max value is a candidate for our global result
        r = max(r, imax);
    }
    return r;
}
```

thanks in advance,
Lin

Comment: Since `imax` and `imin` both start life equal to `r`, your update proposal would keep the two values always equal. Not what you want. (You are aware, I hope, that the code you posted finds the largest product, not subarray itself--as required in the problem statement).

Comment: @TedHopp, do you think we can simplify code by using only imax = max (imin * A[i], max(A[i], imax * A[i])) and imin = min (imin * A[i], min(A[i], imax * A[i])), ad no need to use the if (A[i] < 0) check? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
imax = max(A[i], imax * A[i]);
```

When you consider `A[i]` individually you are basically taking into account the sequence that begins at `A[i]`.

You are doing a similar thing when you initialize the `imin` and `imax` by `A[0]` initially.

Same is true for the `imin` case.

Small Example:

`Array = {-4, 3, 8 , 5}`

Initialization: `imin = -4, imax = -4`

Iteration 1: `i=1 , A[i]=3`

`imax = max(A[i], imax * A[i]);` -> `imax = max(3, -4 * 3);` -> `imax = 3`

So `A[i]` can be maximum when `imax` is negative and `A[i]` is positive.

Comment: Thanks pgiitu for the clarification, but I do not know why we need to consider A[i]? It could never been the largest or smallest, comparing to imax * A[i] and imin * A[i]

Comment: @LinMa - It certainly can when `A[i]` is negative and `imin` is positive! (-2 is larger than 3*-2, for instance).

Comment: @LinMa I have updated the answer with a small example where `A[i]` can be largest in a particular iteration.

Comment: @TedHopp, when you say certainly can, you mean A[i] could be the largest? Or?

Comment: @pgiitu, nice sample!

Comment: @LinMa I hope you understand it now.

Comment: @pgiitu, do you think we can simplify code by using only imax = max (imin * A[i], max(A[i], imax * A[i])) and imin = min (imin * A[i], min(A[i], imax * A[i])), ad no need to use the if (A[i] < 0) check? Thanks.

Comment: @pgiitu, thanks and want to confirm my understanding is correct, imax and imin means, for subarray ends at position i, what is the max and min product value we could get? Thanks.

Comment: @LinMa if it resolved your problem would you mind upvoting and marking my answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MaximumContiguousSubArrayProduct {
    public static int getMaximumContiguousSubArrayProduct(final int... array) {
        if (array.length == 0) {
            return -1;
        }
        int negativeMax = 0, positiveMax = 0, max;
        if (array[0] < 0) {
            negativeMax = array[0];
            max = negativeMax;
        } else {
            positiveMax = array[0];
            max = positiveMax;
        }

        for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i] == 0) {
                negativeMax = 0;
                positiveMax = 0;
                if (max < 0) {
                    max = 0;
                }
            } else if (array[i] > 0) {
                if (positiveMax == 0) {
                    positiveMax = array[i];
                } else {
                    positiveMax *= array[i];
                }
                if (negativeMax != 0) {
                    negativeMax *= array[i];
                }
                if (positiveMax > max) {
                    max = positiveMax;
                }
            } else {
                if (array[i] > max) {
                    max = array[i];
                }
                if (negativeMax == 0) {
                    if (positiveMax != 0) {
                        negativeMax *= positiveMax;
                    } else {
                        negativeMax = array[i];
                    }
                    positiveMax = 0;
                } else {
                    if (positiveMax != 0) {
                        int temp = positiveMax;
                        positiveMax = negativeMax * array[i];
                        negativeMax = temp * array[i];
                    } else {
                        positiveMax = negativeMax * array[i];
                        negativeMax = array[i];
                    }

                    if (positiveMax > max) {
                        max = positiveMax;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return max;
    }

}
```

**Corresponding tests:**

```
import org.junit.Test;

import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.equalTo;
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;

public class MaximumContiguousSubArrayProductTest {
    @Test
    public void testMaximumProductSubArray() {
        assertThat(MaximumContiguousSubArrayProduct.getMaximumContiguousSubArrayProduct(2, 3, -2, 4), equalTo(6));
        assertThat(MaximumContiguousSubArrayProduct.getMaximumContiguousSubArrayProduct(2, 3, -2, 4, 9), equalTo(36));
        assertThat(MaximumContiguousSubArrayProduct.getMaximumContiguousSubArrayProduct(-2, 0, -1), equalTo(0));
        assertThat(MaximumContiguousSubArrayProduct.getMaximumContiguousSubArrayProduct(), equalTo(-1));
        assertThat(MaximumContiguousSubArrayProduct.getMaximumContiguousSubArrayProduct(-1), equalTo(-1));
        assertThat(MaximumContiguousSubArrayProduct.getMaximumContiguousSubArrayProduct(1), equalTo(1));
        assertThat(MaximumContiguousSubArrayProduct.getMaximumContiguousSubArrayProduct(-9, -3, -4, -1), equalTo(9 * 3 * 4));
        assertThat(MaximumContiguousSubArrayProduct.getMaximumContiguousSubArrayProduct(-1, 2), equalTo(2));
        assertThat(MaximumContiguousSubArrayProduct.getMaximumContiguousSubArrayProduct(-100, -1, 99), equalTo(9900));
    }
}
```